# Wind direction + magnitude

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, vector-fields

High winds are blowing 70mph north-northeast.

But is it blowing only in the north-northwest direction? How much is it blowing in the south-southeast direction? How much is it blowing in the southwest direction? (How much is it blowing in both the due north and due east directions? Can you write it as a combination of a direction vector and a magnitude?)

I am not sure how to approach this as I don't really understand how the wind can be blowing in more than one direction? How can you tell by how much the wind is blowing in the other direction if all you have is the final vector after subtraction? For instance, the wind could be blowing 10 mph in the opposite direction but that would cause the north-northeast speed to be reduced to 60.

Comment: Your question as posed doesn't make any sense.  Have you looked at any wind maps on weather-forecast websites, for example?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about English language usage rather than physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is true that you could *combine* two winds from two different directions vectorially to obtain a resultant, you are wrong about how wind directions are specified. Here is how it works:

If the wind is coming from north (compass direction *zero degrees*), it is a north wind. If from the east (compass direction *90 degrees*), it is an east wind. If the direction is halfway between north and east (compass direction *45 degrees*), it is a north-east wind.

Now imagine that the wind is blowing not precisely from the north at zero and not precisely from north-east at 45 but from *halfway between north and north-east* (compass direction *22.5 degrees*), then we call that  direction *north-northeast*.

This does not mean that *meteorologically speaking* any wind is necessarily a vector sum. Your north-northeast wind is most likely originating from a high-pressure zone that is physically located in the compass direction 22.5 degrees.